# Alter protocol version installing from github

Tags: r

I try to install a package from GitHub using this:

```
library(devtools)
install_github(dosorio/Peptides)
```

but I receive this error

> Downloading github repo dosorio/Peptides@master Error in function
>   (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

this error happens with all attempts to install other r package from GitHub

I user 3.0.2 R version in window/Rstudio.

Does it have to do with the R version or anything else?

Comment: `install_github` need a character vector `install_github('dosorio/Peptides')`. Other than that, it's working on my machine with `R 3.4.4`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved the the following commands:

```
git config --global --list
git config --global --unset http.sslVersion
git config --global --add http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

just use
options(download.file.method = "libcurl")

refer:
https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/130